# Can I cap off a 2" x 3" downspout?

Tags: water, downspout

I engineered a downspout with a side hole to divert water.  However, I also need to cap off the bottom of the existing 2"x3" original downspout.

I can't find any "caps" anywhere so they might not exist.  Is there a way to cap off the downspout?

Comment: This isn't a product question and shouldn't be closed as such. Elizabeth, a photo of the exit port would help us provide better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are  not intending to use the downspout for anything but the one purpose than just eliminate the bottom portion all together otherwise you will end up with water just filling up and stagnating in the capped off portion.

Just divert the downspout with bends, 45 or 90 degree bends, to the to point your are collecting the water so there is not a bottom portion to cap off and collect water.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd try to install an internal baffle to divert water at the side exit while preventing the stagnation Alaska man mentions. It would essentially be a sheet metal plate that matches the spout cross-section, with tabs bent at right angles to act as screw mounts (from the outside).

```
|              |
|              |
|                <-- side exit port
|              
| ------------ | <-- baffle plate
||            || <-- tab for screws
|              |
```

You might angle the baffle plate to prevent debris buildup and make for smoother water flow. Of course, this requires the baffle to be elongated.